# WordPress - Changed directory and images do not appear

Tags: wordpress

I changed the folder that my WordPress installation was in.

However, this worked fine, except now all my images are not showing up.

The problem is that each post has the full url of the image in it. (not my doing, this seems to be the default setting)

Is there a tool or a quick fix available for this?

Comment: I have updated the new url in wordpress. The contents of the post themselves have the full url in them. I can't seem to write an update statement on it, because a replace does not work on a text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Update URLs](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/wordpress-plugin-update-urls/) plugin for Wordpress to help you with that. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your settings to reflect the directory change on the settings page in your admin section.

**Edit:**

Since it seems to be a problem in the posts themselves, you'll probably have to write a quick fixme script that runs through your post table searches for `'="/'` or something similar and updates any hardcoded links.